# Can't find the Expo development tools when starting a React Native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a new project like this:

```
npm install --global expo-cli
expo init my-first-react-native-app --template expo-template-blank@sdk-44 --npm
```

When starting the Metro Bundler with `expo start` I can go to http://localhost:19000/ and see something in JSON format like this:

```
{
name: "my-first-react-native-app",
slug: "my-first-react-native-app",
version: "1.0.0",
orientation: "portrait",
icon: "./assets/icon.png",
userInterfaceStyle: "light",
splash: {
image: "./assets/splash.png",
resizeMode: "contain",
backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
imageUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/splash.png"
},
...
...
```

It is supposed that I could go to http://localhost:19002/ and see the Expo development tools as well, but I only get the classical message that goes "This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect"

What is happening here?

Comment: expo-cli@6.0.0 has been released with the web UI removed. The last release to include the web UI is expo-cli@5.5.1. https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

Comment: @Dmitro_ You are right. That, on the one hand, allows me to know that I was not doing it wrong, and on the other hand, makes me be able to follow my tutorial. Thank you so much!